# Angular 10, Modal not showing propper data until a second object is clicked

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

If the user clicks in the edit button, it should displays the data in a form inside a modal, however for some reason it needs to click one user, and then another one to show the data. I even tried putting the id from the object in a "h1" tag and it's displaying it correctly in the first click, not sure why.

[Here is the first click, as you can see in the console it shows the correct data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMft1.png)

And you can even see that the "h1" tag contains the id from the object, but it doesn't show the data in the input tags.

[Here is after clicking in another user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxO5u.png)

It shows all the data correctly after changing to another.

Here are the files that i used.

component.html, this is how i show the data

```
 <input *ngIf="add_modify" type="email" id="name" class="form-control" mdbInput value="{{clicked_user.full_name}}" [(ngModel)]="user.full_name" name="full_name">
 <input *ngIf="!add_modify" type="email" id="name" class="form-control" mdbInput [(ngModel)]="user.full_name" name="full_name">
 <label for="name">Nombres</label>
 <h1 *ngIf="add_modify">{{clicked_user._id}}</h1>
 <a (click)="frame.show(); showUserInfo(el)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_user" class="mr-3">

<tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let el of elements">
    <td>{{el.full_name}}</td>
    <td>{{el.email}}</td>
    <td>{{el.work_station}}</td>
    <td>
       <a (click)="frame.show(); showUserInfo(el)" data-toggle="modal" data target="#add_user" class="mr-3">
          <mdb-icon fas icon="user-edit" class="text-info"></mdb-icon>
       </a>
       <a (click)="deleteUser()">
          <mdb-icon fas icon="user-times" class="text-danger"></mdb-icon>
       </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Component.ts, this is how i get the data for the clicked user

```
showUserInfo(user) {
    this.clicked_user = user;
    console.log(this.clicked_user);
    this.add_modify = true;
    console.log(this.add_modify);
  }
```

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

I never created the new User(), so it wasn't saving the data correctly, i just made a blank User() at the constructor of the component and it worked just fine.